# CKEditor 5 toolbar fixed position

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, css-position, ckeditor5

When you are adding long content in CKEditor 5 classic, on scroll the toolbar becomes fixed to the top in the browser window.
But I have a fixed positioned white logo area with a menu bar beneath and the toolbar appears above them:

[image]

How can I make it stay under my fixed header/navigation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've managed to find the answer:

1. You have to install `npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui`
2. Add to the config:  [`viewportTopOffset : Number`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_ui_panel_sticky_stickypanelview-StickyPanelView.html#member-viewportTopOffset)

example:

```
ClassicEditor.defaultConfig = {
toolbar: {      
    viewportTopOffset : 50,    <-- height of fixed header
    items: [
        'heading',
        '|',
        'highlight',
        '|',
        'bold',
        'italic',
        ...
```